# Websphere/Open-Liberty: Access to Weld-Internal classes

Tags: websphere-liberty, open-liberty

I am fully aware that this might not be a good idea in general, but I am wondering if there is a way to access Weld-internal classes from my deployed application-war.
E.g. org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer
This is not for a production-app but rather for a side-projected related to testing and loading some CDI beans on the fly and performing proper cleanup.
The code I have is working under Wildfly, but fails with java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer. I am certain that the weld implementation/feature has this class.

For sure, this is by design, but I am wondering if there is still a way to achieve it; maybe via configuration to not enforce this strict classloader isolation...
Again, this is only for a very specific testing/development scenario.

Thanks,
Daniel

Comment: Have you tried to make 3rd party libs visible via this `<classloader apiTypeVisibility="spec, ibm-api, stable, third-party"/>`. You need to put it inside `<application>` element.

Comment: yes, indeed it is working with that. actually, it needs more. it needs changes in the weld osgi module regarding what packages are exposed as third-party.
so, i am able to get it working in some way; but not without making changes to the websphere distribution/core jars.

Comment: If you need to change distribution, then I'd strongly suggest to NOT do it, and find a different way to achieve what you need that would be safer and supported ;-)